# How to extract tweets of multiple users at once?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm pretty new to Python, and I'm trying to scrape tweets from Twitter.
I managed to get tweets from one user, but I was wondering if is there a way to get multiple timeline at once?
Or do I have necessarily to scrape users one by one and then join the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets) say there is an https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/tweets

This returns the tweets of a user with the id passed as parameter. By finding out the ids of the users you intend to scrape tweets from and then sending a request for each and parsing/merging the results you are able to achieve your goal.

However, as you stated, you intend to use an easier approach, you intend to send a single request in order to achieve this goal.

You can do a [full search](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all), by hitting the endpoint of https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all but you need your user to be [Approved Research](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-all) for.